# Getting current item from select in Lambda expression?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, lambda

I have a method which takes an `ObservableCollection` as a parameter. I'm using a Lambda expression to populate another list like so:

```
private void DownloadSources(ObservableCollection<DownloadSourcesHelper> SourcesDownloadCollection)
{
    downloadsList =
        SourcesDownloadCollection.Select(GetDownloadCommandParameters)
            .Select(sourceParamters =>
                new DownloadCalculation(DownloadSources.Item currently being iterated here!,
                   ))).ToList();

    foreach (var source in downloadsList )
    {
         blah blah.

    // .....
```

Is there a way for me to get the current `DownloadSources` item?

Comment: Define *current* item please? `ObservableCollection` doesn't have anything like current item by itself.

Comment: So trying to get the SourcesDownloadCollection item currently being enumerated within the select as I need to pass it into my DownloadCalculation object.

Comment: You can create anonymous type with `Select` which will contains `DownloadCalculation` result and current `sourceParamters` value.

Answer (score 1):

Question is either as simple as

```
var list =...Select(o => new DownloadCalculation(o.Item)).ToList(); // current item is o
```

Or you can create anonymous type in select

```
var list = ....Select(o => new { Item = o, Result = new DownloadCalculation(o).ToList() });
foreach (var source in list )
{
    // use source.Item and source.Result
}
```

Perhaps this is your problem (passing value from one `Select` to another):

```
var list = ....Select(o => new {Current = o, Result = GetDownloadCommandParameters }.Select(o => new DownloadCalculation(Current, Result)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are doing MVVM and this code is in a ViewModel?

If so just bind DownloadSources.SelectedItem to a property in your ViewModel, so that you can use it in your linq query.

Comment: Yes, I have a SelectedItem property in the viewmodel. Problem is, there are several items being iterated over, not just the single selected DownloadSource, hence using lists